# What is wrong with my Nginx configuration?

Tags: python, web, nginx

I'm trying to configure Nginx in order to be able to execute Python scripts through CGI.

If I point to: http://myserver.org/scripts/ajaxpost.py and in my configuration I use:

```
location ~ \.py$ {
          root   html;
          fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html/scripts/ajaxpost.py;
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      }
```

It works perfectly. However, I want the configuration to be able to execute any Python script inside the scripts folder doing this, but pointing to http://myserver.org/scripts/ajaxpost.py gives me a 403 error.

```
location ~ \.py$ {
          root   html;
          fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      }
```

What is wrong with the configuration?

Comment: Did you try: fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `/usr/share/nginx/html/scripts$fastcgi_script_name` ?

Comment: I've tried that too. Doesn't work either. I can't seem to find where the problem is.